# bezier triangle patch in 3D

Tags: python

i would like  a python script to draw in 3D a triangle bezier patch

this is an old problem and there must be some old script available to do this somehwere!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Here is [javascript implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855502/860099) with theoretical explanation - this should help you to rewrite it to python.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL [RedBook](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/), ["Chapter 12 Evaluators and NURBS"](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter12.html). C examples [are here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/redbook/). But I really don't think you'll be able to use it on *triangles*, only on quads. If you want to go through the trouble of tesselating *triangle*, pick [spline formula from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), and try to implement it yourself.